# PHP DateTime Format does not respect timezones?

Tags: php, datetime

So I have the following code:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime = new DateTime(date('r', 1440543600), $timezone);

echo $datetime->format('l, F j, Y - h:i A e');
```

This outputs the following:

> Tuesday, August 25, 2015 - 11:00 PM +00:00

You would think it would output:

> Tuesday, August 25, 2015 - 07:00 PM -04:00

How do I get format to output correctly with the set timezone?

Comment: What is the intermediate result of the `date()` call? BTW: I found it more robust to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, which doesn't guess. There, you can use the `'U'` format to directly parse a Unix timestamp.

Comment: check documentation about $timezone: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), where is says for 2nd parameter:

> Note: The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored
>   when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800)
>   or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Based on that, set timezone on DateTime object after you have created it with unix timestamp:

```php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime = new DateTime('@1440543600');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/419400)**</kbd>

Comment: I don't understand why PHP ignores the timezone in those cases. It doesn't make sense, especially when the timestamp is provided.

Comment: @RoboRobok: if timezone is provided, 2nd argument is ignored, that makes perfect sense. And when timestamp is given, timezone is provided.

Comment: What I mean is that when I use something like `new DateTime('@1440543600', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))`, I would expect something like assuming that my timestamp is UNIX and I want the result in New York timezone. How does it make sense to ignore the timezone?

Comment: @RoboRobok: Please read note for `timezone` parameter on this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php . Unix timestamp is already in UTC timezone, so you custom timezone will be ignored.

Comment: I know that, I'm asking for logic behind it. I googled this SO question to find the reasoning.

Comment: @RoboRobok The logic is that 2nd parameter to DateTime construct is timezone, which tells us about timezone of the 1st parameter. But if 1st parameter already has timezone defined, 2nd one is ignored. This makes perfect logic. If you wish to changed timezone, you do that by calling setTimezone method on DateTime object.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought the second parameter is the timezone that we want to convert to, but yeah - what you say makes more sense. So `setTimezone()` is the ultimate method to convert the timezone.

Comment: @RoboRobok yes. 2nd argument is for telling in which timezone is 1st argument. For converting timezone, use method as described.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue isn't in how you are outputting your date but rather how you are inputting it.  The 'r' format option includes time offset.

If you create your DateTime object with a string that is devoid of an offset you will get the expected results.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime = new DateTime("2015-08-20 01:24", $timezone);

echo $datetime->format('l, F j, Y - h:i A e');

$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo "\n";
echo $datetime->format('l, F j, Y - h:i A e');

/* outputs

Thursday, August 20, 2015 - 01:24 AM America/New_York
Thursday, August 20, 2015 - 12:24 AM America/Chicago

*/
```

See [here](https://3v4l.org/17emS) for an example.

Comment: I dont think its as simple as that... replacing `'r'` with `'Y-m-d H:i'` still causes the same issue.

Comment: I would try running echoing out `date('Y-m-d H:i', $timestamp)` to make sure your server is giving you the time offset that you think it is. From what I observe anytime I give the constructor a hardcoded value it behaves in a sane manner.